# Designing Screen in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts2,(jsp) to design page , I need three button on sing line, but  tag is there but there is no  tag in struts2 to design, Please hep me how to do this

Comment: please be more specific and  question is unclear !!

Comment: i need to design login page in struts2, so i require three button Clear,login,cancel button on login page, that three button should be in  single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by there are no tag for your requirement? i suggest you to refer with [tag references](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/tag-reference.html) and see what all tags you can use.

For clear button you can use S2 [reset](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/reset.html) tag 
for Login a simple [submit button](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/submit.html) will work for you

S2 does not force you to use its tag and you are all free to use simple HTML tags as per your requirement.

By default S2 use x_html theme which will generate some HTML (table,TR and TD) while rendering the tags.
If you want S2 not to use any extra HTML use [simple theme](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/struts-2-themes.html) and which will let you to use any CSS and design your screen as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can have one div inside place your button

```
div button{
    display:inline-block;
}   



<div style="width:500px;">
            <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;" >Save</button>
            <button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">Publish</button>
            <button class="msgBtnBack">Back</button>
        </div>
```